# Access maven from the terminal

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, apache

I am newbie to Mac world! After unzipping the apache-maven binaries, I was trying to check its version from the terminal using a command,

mvn -v

But there I saw message restricting me its access, here is the screen shot.

[image]

Do I need to have any other permissions to access this?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.owsiak.org/libjansi-jnilib-cannot-be-opened-because-the-developer-cannot-be-verified-macos-10-15/)?

Comment: Yes, it worked! thanks @cafertayyar!

Comment: @caf Please leave this as an answer!

Comment: @SteveChambers Yes, The fix - System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> check Allow Anywhere worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer suggested by @cafertayyar that worked for me.

System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Allow Anyway

as in below screen shot

[image]